# Android WebView loadDataWithBaseURL with link equals BaseURL works incorrectly

Tags: android, webview, href

I load HTML to my WebView with

```
this.webViewer.loadDataWithBaseURL(BASE_URL, completeNewsTemplate,
                "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Where BASE_URL = "http://www.example.ru" i use it for WebView loading images with relative images src's

if in HTML soruce i got href link like

```
<a href="http://www.example.ru" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Then it's just reload current webview, and target attribute does make anything for open new window.

How make webview open link in new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution.

If your link equals base url WebView think that you want work with current page only.

You can try catch it like

```
webViewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                System.out
                    .println("DetailViewActivity.onCreate(...).new WebViewClient() {...}.onPageStarted()");
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            System.out
                    .println("DetailViewActivity.onCreate(...).new WebViewClient() {...}.onPageFinished()");
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out
                    .println("DetailViewActivity.onCreate(...).new WebViewClient() {...}.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()");
                return false;

            }

        });
```

But then you click to your link in webView you never get fired **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** or **onPageStarted** only **onPageFinished** with your base_url.

So my solition is use for base url another domain without **www** prefix.

Here example if you domain www.example.com use base url example.com